# Is it possible to use multiple fields for Solr term facet?

Tags: solr, facet

Given I have existing documents:

```
[
    {"forename":"Will","surname":"Smith",...},    
    {"forename":"Adam","surname":"Smith",...},
    {"forename":"Will","surname":"Anderson",...},
    {"forename":"Will","surname":"Smith",...}

]
```

Would it be possible to use multiple fields for term facet like this?

```
{
    "countSomething":
    {
        "type": "terms",
        "field": "forename,surname"
    }
}
```

So that I may have count of concatenated field? The field type can be number as well

```
{
"buckets":
[
    {
        "val": "Will_Smith",
        "count": 2
    },{
        "val": "Adam_Smith",
        "count": 1
    }{
        "val": "Will_Anderson",
        "count": 1
    }
]}
```

Comment: No, not really. The usual solution is to add a separate field with the facet format you want, since otherwise generating a facet can become very expensive (it is no longer a lookup against token counts and docvalues).